# Logging Nginx and uWSGI web server errors to Sentry

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, sentry, raven

I am currently using Sentry to log application level errors from Django web application. Could it be possible to expand the scope of the Sentry to include logging of web server errors (HTTP 408 timeouts and such)?

These requests never hit the application, so Django + Python logging configuration never sees it. But from the devops perspective these might be equally important error conditions need to deal with.

- Does Nginx or uWSGI support logging directly to Sentry with some addons? (Raven logging adapter?)
- Does Sentry support error capture from Apache like log-files, syslog or such?

Comment: It would make sense to capture errors from log files.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [SentryLogs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SentryLogs) or you could use a Nginx custom `error_page` which fires off to Sentry.